# Bugs when multiplying numbers with bitwise operators

Tags: c++, floating-point, bit-manipulation, multiplication

I am trying to multiply two floating-point numbers using bitwise operators in IEEE-754 format. The 32-bit number is composed in the form *sign - exponent - mantissa*. After multiplying each number, the resultant answer is correct some of the time but not all of the time.

I think it has something to do with the resulting answer not being in normalized form (e.g. 1.1010101 * 2<sup>5</sup>), but I don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <csdtdio>

struct Real
{    
   int sign;
   long exponent;
   unsigned long fraction;
};

Real Multiply(Real Val1, Real Val2){
   Real answer;
   answer.fraction = left.fraction + right.fraction;
   answer.exponent = left.exponent  + right.exponent;
   answer.sign = left.sign ^ right.sign;
   return  answer;
}
```

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve] with examples of what isn't working?

Comment: Is <csdtdio> a typo? If so, then we can assume that that is not your actual code? If so, does your real code perhaps *multiply* the fractions (it should)? Please always post your actual code, not something that may contain typos. The answer assumes you are really adding the fractions.

Answer (score 4):

While multiplying the mantissa parts must be multiplied together, not add

> (-1)<sup>sign1</sup> × 2<sup>exp1</sup> × mantissa1 * (-1)<sup>sign2</sup> × 2<sup>exp2</sup> × mantissa2
>   = (-1)<sup>sign1 + sign2</sup> × 2<sup>exp1 + exp2</sup> × mantissa1 × mantissa2

And you don't need a separate variable for returning

```
Real Multiply(Real Val1, Real Val2){
   Val1.fraction *= Val2.fraction;
   Val1.exponent += Val2.exponent;
   Val1.sign ^= Val2.sign;
   return Val1;
}
```

After those basic things you'll still have to do normalization, for which you need to get the full result instead of just the low bits like the normal non-widening multiplication. Therefore you must cast your "fraction" (if you're using IEEE-754 then the correct term for it is *significand*) to a wider type. Depending on which platform you're on, you may or may not have a type twice as big as an `unsigned long`. It's better to used fixed-width types like `int32_t`, `uint64_t` in this case. That's all the hints needed to do this

Comment: This doesn't normalise the result, but it's a big step in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, generally in such scenarios, you do want a separate result variable. You want numbers like these to be immutable, so the result must be a new one.